# Most durable exhaust hanger?

Tags: exhaust

I have a 2004 f150 and the exhaust hangers have rotted off except that last one at the very back (hook though rubber isolator).

My exhaust pipe keeps twisting so that the tailpipe is against the passenger side rear quarter panel behind the wheel where the pipe sticks out (so it's trying to tilt up).

I've tried some different hangers and they don't hold up, they break after a couple weeks even though my commute is pretty smooth on paved roads. Any suggestions for how to hang this exhaust to keep it from rotating? And a durable hanger that is very strong and corrosion resistant (salt roads in Michigan)?

Comment: Something is bent and out of line here, either the built-in part of the stock exhaust hanger, or the exhaust system itself. Even in Michigan weather with salt on the roads, the stock hanger should last for several years.

Comment: Well it IS 15 years old. The salt here is EXTREMELY hard on vehicles. All of the stock hangers except that last one have rotted and broken. The only remaining one is a hook welded to the pipe and goes up and through a rubber block that isolates vibration. It's nearly slipping out of that as well. I imagine something IS bent because it's nearly unsupported. Do you know of any decent aftermarket exhaust hangers?

Comment: I always found going to an exhaust shop, choosing the most solid chunky rubbers and then making the brackets to fit.

Comment: @SolarMike yeah I might just break down and have the pros come up with something. I've tried to fix it 3 times and it just won't hold.

Comment: I had to make the exhaust and its brackets from scratch as I fitted a v8 into a landrover...

Comment: For an older and worn vehicle, I think you're not going to find anything aftermarket other than general-fit mounts, and would be better off having a muffler shop put something together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @David's comment - something is bent or twisted, especially as you say the pipe keeps twisting round. Check and fix that and you should find they last longer as they won't be under so much stress.

Look at the shape of the pipe, and check it's running where it should - particularly look for any damage to the pipe, and make sure the joints are lined up correctly, as it's easy to end up with a twist there, especially if they are sleeve type joints. Are the engine mounts in good condition (too much movement at the engine end will stress the whole system)?

Once you've made sure it's all lined up right, then follow Mike's advise and buy the chunkiest rubbers your local shop has, and weld up some suitable brackets.

I've just replaced part of the exhaust on my wife's 20 year old car, and it all lined up correctly on the original brackets using the existing rubbers (no idea if they were original) - and we have a lot of salt here too...